# Disable voice notifications on SGS2/Android 2.3?

Tags: notifications, text-to-speech

I don't know what I've modified recently, but my Samsung Galaxy SII (running stock Android 2.3) keeps notifying me vocally whenever I get an incoming call or an SMS.

Is there a way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look under SETTINGS > ACCESSIBILITY for Talkback or something similar. Also check under settings of individual apps - Phone/Dialer and Messaging.

Finally check to ensure that DRIVING MODE has not been recently enabled. That might also be the cause. Look under SETTINGS > VOICE INPUT